# Create a fill-in variable in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

In word I'm using the following to insert a text from an input box in a designated area in word:

```
Sub OpenWord()


   Dim var1 As String
   var1 = InputBox("vul!")

   Documents.Open ("C:\Documents and Settings\aa471714\Desktop\TEMP BESTANDEN/Doc2.doc")
   ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Test").Select
   Selection.Text = var1


End Sub
```

I know would like to create to same function for something in powerpoint. So what I did in word (classifying a bookmark area in word as "test" and then fill in a variable there) in want to do in powerpoint as well. Define an object in some way so I can fill in a variable there.

Anybody a clue on how I have to do this in PPT?

Comment: Sure it's possible. Try to break it down in to smaller problems and solve them one by one: show textbox, save string, open all presentations, update text in all presentations. If you get stuck, ask specific questions about your problem. I doubt you'll get a complete solution from SO, but you never know.

Comment: Ok, will try to split it in more specific parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the basics of what you need.

```
Sub WriteToTextBox()
Dim tb As Shape
Dim sld As Slide
Dim pres As Presentation
Dim var1 As String


var1 = InputBox("Var1")
Set pres = ActivePresentation
Set sld = pres.Slides(23) 'Modify as needed

Set tb = sld.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 100, 100, 100, 50) 'Modify dimensions as needed
    tb.name = "unique name"  '< assign a unique name to the textbox so you can refer to it later
    tb.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = var1



End Sub

Sub ReadFromTextBox()
Dim s$
Dim sld As Slide
Dim pres As Presentation
Set pres = ActivePresentation
Set sld = pres.Slides(23) 'Modify as needed


s = sld.Shapes("unique name").TextFrame.TextRange.Text 'Read the value from the textbox
MsgBox s 

End Sub
```